# Using HttpDo In P5.s

Tags: p5.js

I'm trying to request some data from a local python server using p5.js it works perfectly fine just when I tried to execute in the request I got this error:

Data expected to be returned: `[['Test', "1002'\n"], ['Player1', "1002'\n"]]`

[image: error shown]

Code:

```js
function getdata(){
    let url = "http://localhost:8080"
    httpDo(
        url,
        {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
            haeder: {'Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'}

        },
        function(res){
            print(res)
        },
        
    )
    
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have a CORS error. Have you tried pasting that error message into google?

Comment: @kevin-workman yes I have tried to fix it myself